# Comparing day ranges with Django

Tags: python, django

My table has two columns which store the days that particular deals start on and end on. The values of these columns are ints, and follow the same pattern the datetime library that Python uses.

My logic currently works for day ranges that don't wrap around the week, ie. Monday-Friday, Thursday-Saturday, Tuesday-Thursday etc. I'm not sure how to catch deals that fall into the next week, such as Friday-Monday, Saturday-Tuesday, etc. Here's my statement using Django:

```
Deal.objects.filter(Q(deal_day_start__lte=current_day) & Q(deal_day_end__gte=current_day))
```

Obviously this gives me issues for ranges Friday - Monday, since the current day for example can be Sunday, which is a 0 in datetime, and the deal start day is a 5 for Friday.

Is there an easy way to solve this using Django? If I was using Python if else statements I could obviously create several branches and capture this scenario, but I'm not sure how to go about this using Django.

Comment: an int representing the weekday only is a horrible idea ... rethink your database schema ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley No worries. Early enough in the project that I can change it. How do you recommend storing the days in a week and using them for comparison?

Comment: just store the timestamp of the start day and end date ... that way you have all the info

Comment: @JoranBeasley I could do that...but a lot of deals are not specific to certain days, they are reoccurring on a weekly basis (deal is on every week, Monday - Wednesday, for example), which is why I am only storing the weekday in my database. If I were to store  the timestamp, I could extract the weekday out of it in code, but then I am back at my original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the used schema I would propose:

```
Deal.objects.filter(
  Q(deal_day_start__lte=current_day, deal_day_end__gte=current_day) | 
  Q(deal_day_start__lte=current_day, deal_day_end__lt=F("deal_day_start")) | 
  Q(deal_day_start__gte=current_day, deal_day_end__gte=current_day, deal_day_end__lt=F("deal_day_start"))
)
```

Let's make the observation that for a deal to wrap the end day must be smaller than the start day. We have 3 cases for current day to belong to a deal period:

- If the current day is between start and end day.
- If the current day is greater than the start day but greater that the end day, then it means that the deal must wrap.
- If the current day is smaller than the start date, then the deal must wrap. But not only wrap but also finish after the current day.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75228/discussion-on-answer-by-juniorcompressor-comparing-day-ranges-with-django).

Comment: @foadster I added explanation.